# PHP drop down menu

Tags: php, selected

I want to get values of the selected items from 3 drop down menus ( years , month and day) using PHP  , 
I tried this but didn't work

```
<p><font size="6"> <b>TP3</b></font></p>
     <p>
     </p>
     <table align="center" width="800" border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
     <tr>
     <td><p><?php echo "Date : " . date("Y/m/d") . "<br>";?></p><br/>
<?php $date = new DateTime();
$day = $date->format('d');
$month = $date->format('m');
$year = $date->format('Y'); ?>
<select name="day">
    <option value="day" selected="selected">Day</option>
    <?php 
    for($i=1; $i<=31; $i++)
        {
            printf('<option value="%d" %s>%d</option>', $i, $i == $day ? 'selected="selected"' : '', $i);
        }
?> 
</select>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<select name="month">
    <option value="month" selected="selected">Month</option>
    <?php 
    for($i=1; $i<=12; $i++)
        {
            echo "<option value=".$i.">".$i."</option>";
        }
?> 
</select>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<select name="years">
    <option value="years" selected="selected">Years</option>
    <?php 
    for($i=2000; $i<=2020; $i++)
        {
            echo "<option value=".$i.">".$i."</option>";
        }
?> 
</select> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Verify Date">
```

Comment: Can you format the code so that the whole thing displays in your question.

Comment: How does it not work? In its current form this is *not* a good question.

Comment: I don't see any form tags.

Comment: either post the form to get the values in php or use javascript to get the selected options

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you're missing `<form></form>` tags (***this is very important***).

- Then a method (GET or POST), but we'll be using POST for this: `method="post"`.
  `<form>` defaults to GET if the method is omitted, *a quick FYI*.
- Then there's the action (see further down below for an examle). The action determines if you wish to execute and show the data pulled in from your form inside the same file `action=""`
  or using an external file `action="handler.php"`.

Here:

```
<p><font size="6"> <b>TP3</b></font></p>
     <p>
     </p>
     <table align="center" width="800" border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
     <tr>
     <td><p><?php echo "Date : " . date("Y/m/d") . "<br>";?></p><br/>
<?php $date = new DateTime();
$day = $date->format('d');
$month = $date->format('m');
$year = $date->format('Y'); ?>

<form action="" method="post">
<select name="day">
    <option value="day" selected="selected">Day</option>
    <?php 
    for($i=1; $i<=31; $i++)
        {
            printf('<option value="%d" %s>%d</option>', $i, $i == $day ? 'selected="selected"' : '', $i);
        }
?> 
</select>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<select name="month">
    <option value="month" selected="selected">Month</option>
    <?php 
    for($i=1; $i<=12; $i++)
        {
            echo "<option value=".$i.">".$i."</option>";
        }
?> 
</select>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<select name="years">
    <option value="years" selected="selected">Years</option>
    <?php 
    for($i=2000; $i<=2020; $i++)
        {
            echo "<option value=".$i.">".$i."</option>";
        }
?> 
</select> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Verify Date">

</form>
```

Plus, I don't know what type of action you wish to use, that will be up to you to decide.

So change `action=""` to the file handler you wish to use.

I.e.: `action="handler.php"` and do your magic from there.

Example of `handler.php`: and will produce for example `Day: 14 Month: 10 Year: 2014`

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$day  = $_POST['day'];

$month = $_POST['month'];

$year = $_POST['years'];

echo "Day: " . $day . " ";

echo "Month: " . $month . " ";

echo "Year: " . $year;

}

?>
```

You can place the above inside its own file, or place it below:

```
// rest of code from your form/code

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Verify Date">

</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$day  = $_POST['day'];

// rest of code
```

---

I believe this has answered your question.

- [**Mark it**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/) as accepted to close the question properly:

[image]

- **The full article: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/**

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need to add your `<form action="action.php" method="post"></form>` tags so the browser knows where to post the data to. In your "action.php" file, you can retrieve the values the user set the controls to when the form is submitted using the `$_POST` array:

```
$day = $_POST['day'];
$month = $_POST['month'];
$year = $_POST['year'];
```

*EDIT*: If you wish to use the GET method instead of POST, then simply replace `$_POST` with `$_GET`.

Answer (score 0):

```
   Try it


 <p><font size="6"> <b>TP3</b></font></p>
         <p>
         </p>
         <table align="center" width="800" border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
         <tr>
         <td><p><?php echo "Date : " . date("Y/m/d") . "<br>";?></p><br/>
    <?php $date = new DateTime();
    $day = $date->format('d');
    $month = $date->format('m');
    $year = $date->format('Y'); ?>
    <select name="day">
        <option value="day" selected="selected">Day</option>
        <?php 
        $i=1;
        for($i=1; $i<=31; $i++)
            {
                printf('<option value="%d" %s>%d</option>', $i, $i == $day ? 'selected="selected"' : '', $i);
            }
    ?> 
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <select name="month">
        <option value="month" selected="selected">Month</option>
        <?php 
        $i=1;
        for($i=1; $i<=12; $i++)
            {
                echo "<option value=".$i.">".$i."</option>";
            }
    ?> 
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <select name="years">
        <option value="years" selected="selected">Years</option>
        <?php 
        $i=2000;
        for($i=2000; $i<=2020; $i++)
            {
                echo "<option value=".$i.">".$i."</option>";
            }
    ?> 
    </select> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Verify Date">
```